# How i make a button text to lower case in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Anyone tell me how I make my button to lowercase in react native because I already get the answer in stack overflow but there is using touch opacity and that is the different component of button so I want the answer for button component

When I will type anything in under title props example
`title='Hello'`

[1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmaBF.png

Comment: Share your code, are you using button from react-native or another package ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use TouchableOpacity for your button
like this:

```
<TouchableOpacity
    onPress={() => onClick}
    style={{}}>
    <Text
      style={{
        fontSize: 20,
        alignSelf: 'center',
      }}>
      Hello
    </Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 1):

Install `react-native-paper` and import `Button` from `react-native-paper` and make `uppercase` prop to false.

```
import { Button } from 'react-native-paper';
    
<Button
    mode="contained"
    uppercase={false}
    onPress={() => console.log('Hello')}>
    Hello
</Button>
```

Comment: I think you don't know about button because now I understand about how we deal with button and also button has a self closing tag so you will not be use different button close like this </Button>

Comment: check this https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/button.html

Answer (score 0):

From your question I just understood that you only need to convert the button text to lower case. For that just replace  `{title}` with `{title.toLowerCase()}` and it will convert the titles text to lower case.